# Change Activity Button State from Adapter

Tags: listview, button, android-activity, adapter

I have a ListView in my Activity, and I have to change my DeleteButton state (VISIBLE - GONE), when user checks/unchecks the checkboxes on any of ListView's items.

I tried doing something like this:

```
holder.cb_row_adminNotesCheck
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                        mNotesList.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
                        if (isChecked) {
                            map.put(getPosition, true);
                        } else {
                            map.remove(getPosition);
                        }
                        setDeleteButtonVisibility();

                    }
                });
..
private void setDeleteButtonVisibility() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Button deleteButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.adminnotes,
            null).findViewById(R.id.ib_adminnotesDeleteMore);

    deleteButton.setVisibility(statesMap.size() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

but nothing happens with my DeleteButton. I debugged app, and everything seems fine, but the "recognising" of DeleteButton with:

```
activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adminnotes,
            null).findViewById(R.id.ib_adminnotesDeleteMore);
```

and setting it to VISIBLE / GONE.

PS. Note that deleteButton is not a row button, it is from main activity with the entire listview.

Any valuable answer will be thanked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I missed smth, but the only way I managed to do so, was by making the DeleteButton variable - public and static (inside Activity),  and accessing it in the Adapter in onCheckedChange method.